# Sign xml with smart card taking too long

Tags: java, security, digital-signature, smartcard, digital-certificate

i'm working on a Project that uses digital signature, both physical or not (smart card or file).
I need to sign a hundred pieces of xml code per file, by now there are 2500 files, so it means 2500 * 100 = 250,000 times. While using a1 certificate (file) it takes 2 seconds per file. When I try smart card it takes 30 seconds per file, meaning all files would take almost 21 hours, which is tooo long.
I'd like to know if anyone has ever dealt with that, btw it's Java code, a snippet follows.

```
    Element elemento = (Element) document.getElementsByTagName(elementName).item(0);
    elemento.setIdAttribute("id", true);
    String id = elemento.getAttribute("id");

    Init.init();

    ElementProxy.setDefaultPrefix(Constants.SignatureSpecNS, "");
    XMLSignature sig = new XMLSignature(document, "", XMLSignature.ALGO_ID_SIGNATURE_RSA_SHA256);

    elemento.getParentNode().appendChild(sig.getElement());

    {
        Transforms transforms = new Transforms(document);
        transforms.addTransform(Transforms.TRANSFORM_ENVELOPED_SIGNATURE);
        transforms.addTransform(Transforms.TRANSFORM_C14N_OMIT_COMMENTS);
        sig.addDocument("#" + id, transforms, "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256");
    }

    XmlUtils.trimWhitespace(document);
    XmlUtils.scapeChars(document);

    {
        X509Certificate cert = certificadoBean.getCertificate();
        sig.addKeyInfo(cert);
        sig.sign(certificadoBean.getPrivateKey());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While 30 seconds is too long for a single operation, the cheap hardware (smartcards and USB tokens) is indeed very slow, and single operation usually takes 2-3 seconds. You need to use a faster hardware device for your task. For example, industry-level PKI devices (specialized hardware accelerators and appliances) perform signing in a fraction of second.

Comment: Thank you so much Eugene, I've tried parallel execution, it increased 2 sec per execution. Don't you have any idea I could try to improve at least some more seconds?

Comment: @LanaStf I would try to ensure, that it's hardware which adds slowness. If you can use the same hardware in any other signing operation besides Java signing code, it would be great to test the hardware. Maybe the hardware vendor offer an application or there's some other unmanaged (not-Java) way to test your device.

Comment: Doesn't the fact that a1 run 16x faster ensure it?

Comment: @LanaStf the comparison I suggest is not between the certificate stored on the disk and the certificate in hardware, but between managed vs. unmanaged code. I'd try to exclude the factor of Java-to-hardware interop.

Comment: @LanaStf We had a similar problem as you. In my case, the delays are network related, so we implemented threads, 5 to be exact. The application signed 200000 files and generated their respective xml files in 20 hours. Before that implementation the process took about 80 hours to complete. So threads are a good option.

Comment: First of all, thanks to comment. I did that also, in my case, User inputs n files, I split files into 4 stacks then create a single thread for each quarter, that runs its files synchronously inside a loop, so there are 4 executions at the same time. But, 'cause files have to be signed a hundred time each, I split file itself in two more threads, 50 nodes to each one, so I guess there are 4 threads + 8 'subthreads', but it's still quite slow

Answer (score 0):

I can't recognize from your code, where the hashing takes place. If the card hashes, the amount of data required to be transmitted is surely the bottleneck. Consider hashing on the host side. Performing only the signature operation on card should take something in the sub-second range.

Comment: I thought that would work this way already, internally. Can smart card digest value as well?

Comment: @Some cards support hashing, but due to I/O bandwidth this is seldom used.